# Save a Mail::Part as a carrierwave attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave, email-attachments

I am trying to implement a feature where I need to parse an email from s3 and extract its attachments into a carrierwave uploader : I need to save a `Mail::Part` as a carrierwave attachment.

I am reading an email stored in s3, and parsing it using the mailer gem, so I basically end up with a multipart email. So far I'm already done with the parsing of the body , but now I need to handle email attachments.

I am here:

```rb
s3 = ::Aws::S3::Encryption::Client.new(
  region: 'eu-west-1',
  kms_key_id: 'my-key',
)
object = s3.get_object(
  bucket: bucket,
  key: key,
)
s3_email = object.body.read
mail = ::Mail.new(s3_email) # Mail::Message
mail.attachments
# => [#<Mail::Part:70154514749400, Multipart: true, Headers: <Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="------------0739BEA5795DFFE28DCBAECD">>, #<Mail::Part:70154514744360, Multipart: false, Headers: <Content-Type: application/pdf; x-mac-type="0"; x-mac-creator="0"; name="my_attachment.pdf">, <Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64>, <Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my_attachment.pdf">>]
```

And I need to store it as a carrierwave uploader

```rb
class Message
  include Mongoid::Document
  mount_uploader :attachment, ::AttachmentUploader
end

# Message.new(attachment: mail.attachments.first) ==> I want to do something like this
```

I am not sure of how I can transfer this as a Carrierwave attachment.

Also, I know about Griddler, but this gem does not seem to contain the code I am looking for (or maybe I missed it)

EDIT

I am trying to follow the instructions from here https://github.com/mikel/mail#testing-and-extracting-attachments with a tempfile but things do not go as planned

```rb
tempfile = Tempfile.new(filename)
tempfile.write(attachment.decoded)
# => *** Encoding::UndefinedConversionError Exception: "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

Comment: Can you just do this? `mail.attachments.filename #=> 'test.png'` That returns the attachment by filename or at index. And then you can wrap that response in `Message.new(attachment: File.open('test.png''))`? or is that not going to work?

Comment: I have edited my question. I am reading the multipart email from an AWS S3 file, so all I have is the "raw" multipart file and the parsed version from the mailer gem. I do not know how I can extract the attachment multipart version into a file, that's what I am trying to do ^^ Something like `email.attachments.first.to_file` except this does not work

Answer (score 2):

So actually there were two tricks to it

- Using the `b` flag to write bytes directly, which avoids the encoding problem
- Making sure the file has the same extension as the original file. by default, using Tempfiles will mess up the extension, and knowing that carrierwave has an extension whitelist, this would mess up the validation of your attachment

The following worked for me

```rb
# Map attachments to files that can be added via carrierwave
email.attachments.map do |attachment|
  filename = attachment.filename
  extension = File.extname(filename)
  # Produce a nice tmpfile with human readable display name and preserve the extension 
  tempfile = Tempfile.new([File.basename(filename, extension) + '-', extension])
  # The `b` flag is important
  File.open(tempfile, 'wb') { |f| f.write(attachment.decoded) }
  tempfile
end
```

This has the disadvantage of having to write a file to the disk (while that file was already parsed in memory). I'm still wondering if there is a way to store a file in carrierwave without having to resort to that (since the file still needs to be cleaned/removed after)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't think I would get it, but here it is...

```
attachment = mail.attachments.first
File.open('/Users/me/temp.jpg', 'w', encoding: 'ascii-8bit') do |f|
   f.write attachment.body.decoded
end
```

So, that's how you would write a new file. But you can use `Tempfile` in a similar way:

```
f = Tempfile.new(['temp', '.jpg'], encoding: 'ascii-8bit')
f.write attachment.body.decoded
message = Message.new(attachment: File.open(f))
```

Please let me know if this works for you. I tested it by manually attaching an image to an email and then reversing that process from the sent mail. I'm not sure how your AWS S3 bucket might change things.

Comment: Thanks, after re-reading the mail gem github and some related questions/github issues, I found out that the `b` flag was actually rather important when opening the file and would automatically avoid those problems of having to write the encoding. Also using tempfiles without precautions adds the uid after the extension which kinda messes the Carrierwave validation behavior.

Comment: Our solutions are somewhat similar. You were right about the extension, I cleaned that up, but using the `b` flag is essentially an alias for your encoding AFAIK so I don't think that is much better. `TempFile` is pretty ugly for injecting that data in the filename, but I don't think much can be done about that!